# Why this code is not restricted to an OU?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to query the Active directory to get a list of users in my asp.net/C# application.

I have this code :

```
    adProvider = "LDAP";
    adPath = "DC00.Domain.prv/OU=Sub,OU=Users,OU=Test,DC=Domain,DC=prv";
    entry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("{0}://{1}", adProvider, adPath),"AD","ThePwd"); 
    DirectorySearcher searcher1 = new DirectorySearcher(entry);


    searcher1 = new DirectorySearcher("objectClass=user");

    SearchResultCollection results1;
    results1 = searcher1.FindAll();
    var list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < results1.Count; i++)
    {

        list.Add(results1[i].Properties["cn"][0].ToString());
    }
    return list;
```

It is working because I get a list of 1000 "common name" from users but.. In facts the `Test/Users/Sub` OU have only one user.. It seems the request is searching for users in the all AD range..

What is wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe I'm wrong but you overwrite the variable searcher1 twice :

This second overwrite is useless if you want to use the first one...

```
searcher1 = new DirectorySearcher("objectClass=user");
```

Comment: No, you just need a little pause, go take a coffee and see the sun and then all will be fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Be carreful using the filter `"objectClass=user"` you are going to collect users and computers you'd better use :

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```